# How to locate links from Google results

Tags: selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver, automation, webdriver

Scenario:

1. open "google.co.in".
2. click in the search input box.
3. type something.
4. click Enter.
5. get the text of all links.

The xpaths of some links are:

- `.//*[@id='rso']/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div/h3/a`
- `.//*[@id='rso']/div[2]/div/div[3]/div/div/h3/a`
- `.//*[@id='rso']/div[2]/div/div[4]/div/div/h3/a`
- `.//*[@id='rso']/div[2]/div/div[5]/div/div/h3/a`
- `.//*[@id='rso']/div[2]/div/div[6]/div/div/h3/a`

All the xpaths have the same pattern. the third div needs to be incremented by 1 to get the next xpath. I've read somewhere that in the scenarios like this generic xpath can be used. According to his suggestion, the xpath will be `".//*[@id='rso']/div[2]/div/div/div/div/h3/a"`. just removed the predicate of the third div. This is not working. Is this the way to locate elements?

Comment: Please add your code attempts and add a tag for the language you are using.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try below XPath to fetch all result links:

```
//div[@class="g"]//h3/a
```

If you want to avoid links from "People also ask" block:

```
//div[@class="g"]//h3/a[not(ancestor::div[@class="_OKe"])]
```

Comment: Your locator is finding elements in the "People also ask" section that isn't part of the search results.

Comment: @JeffC , Yep, you're right. My settings were incorrect (Note that for Germany locale there is no "People also ask" block on Google result page). Updated

Comment: Interesting... were you going to your local google page or were you using google.co.in as OP was?

Comment: The same behavior on google.co.in and google.de. And "People also ask" appears if to use google.co.in/search?hl=en or google.de/search?hl=en

Comment: List <WebElement> my_list = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@class=\"g\"]//h3/a[not(ancestor::div[@class=\"_OKe\"])]"));
  for (WebElement item:my_list)
  {

      String text = item.getAttribute("innerHTML");
      System.out.println("Heading is : " + text);
  }

Comment: Used the above code but I'm not getting link texts in console output.

Comment: Why do you use `item.getAttribute("innerHTML")` to get link text?